# Propagate action between react components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So, I have re-used a login/register modal and added a `Modal` to be able to show/hide it.

So I have implementend in the `index.js` below:

```
const Form = ({ initialState = STATE_SIGN_UP, showPopUp = STATE_HIDE }) => {
  const [mode, toggleMode] = useToggle(initialState);
  const [display, toggleDisplay] = useToggleDisplay(showPopUp);

 
  return (
    <Modal className="modal" show={showPopUp}  size="lg">
        <Container pose={mode === STATE_LOG_IN ? "signup" : "login"}>
        <div className="container__form container__form--one">
            <FormLogin mode={mode} />
        </div>
        <div className="container__form container__form--two">
            <FormSignup mode={mode} />
        </div>
        <Overlay toggleMode={toggleMode} mode={mode} />
        </Container>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

and I have added in `FormLogin` a close `icon` and added `onClick`. I used a `console.log` to verify if it's working. However, I do not understand how to be able to send and make the modal in the `index.js` closed when the action on `close` happened in the `FormLogin` class.

I tried to use the `toggleDisplay` but I have lost my track doing it. `toogleDisplay` is done as below:

```
export const STATE_SHOW = true
export const STATE_HIDE = false

const useToggleDisplay = initialState => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(initialState)
  const toggleDisplay = () =>
    setDisplay(display === STATE_SHOW ? STATE_HIDE : STATE_SHOW)
  return [display, toggleDisplay]
}

export default useToggleDisplay
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an `onClose` handler(which equals `toggleMode` here) to your modal and call it every time the close button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `toggleDisplay` in order to close your modal, pass it into your form component

```
<FormLogin mode={mode} toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay} />
```

Then inside FormLogin component wherever your click handler is for closing the modal pass in `toggleDisplay(false)`

```
<button onClick={() => toggleDisplay(false)}>Close</button>
```

Comment: is it toggleDisplay or useToggleDisplay which needs to be called in onClick ?